# My company uses forcepoint to snoop on its employees. Are my passwords safe?

Tags: security

We have heard that the forcepoint SW running on all our companies corporate laptops decrypts all ssl traffic, including web pages and chat clients (skype, whatsapp, skype for business etc).

This implies that the companies It department have full access to everything, including our banking passwords, email passwords etc.  Not just which websites we visit (which I dont mind)

Could someone who knows what forcepoint can do explain how it works and what it can and cant see?

Interestingly, the local IT support guys blame forcepoint for the fact that performance for things like video conferencing using skype for business is so bad, and suggest using non-company laptops on guest networks for critical company calls, which seems crazy.

Comment: "the local IT support guys blame forcepoint for the fact that performance for things like video conferencing using skype for business is so bad" They are likely correct.

Comment: I have said this over and over, whatever you do on a network belonging to someone else, including (maybe especially) an employer's network, is compromised and can be seen by the network owner.

Comment: You should not use non-company laptops for critical company calls. This is not what management want or they would not deploy Force point. If they do want this they should buy you laptops for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

No. Your passwords are not safe. I've never heard of Force point, but according to https://www.forcepoint.com/product/insider-threat this software can, among other things, do key logging - this  captures when you type your password in to the system thus information can be recorded.

From your POV, might I suggest you are working on a system that is, effectively, compromised, and under the full control of others. You should not trust it at all for your personal stuff. (Even if Forcepoint does not disclose your personal information other software can.)

Comment: To answer another part of your question, it can see everything. It purports to use heuristics (AI analog) to determine what to do with the information it is pricey to.